# don't want xslt intepret the entity characters

Tags: xslt, entity, special-characters, xslt-1.0, apostrophe

The xml was like this:

```
< cell i='0' j='0' vi='0' parity='Odd' subType='-1'> & #34;String& #39;</cell>
```

But after the intepretion of the xsl, the output is like this:

```
< td nowrap="true" class="gridCell" i="0" j="0">"String'< /td>
```

I would like to keep the & #34; and & #39;. I've tried character map,but it doesn't work. The code is like this:

```
      < xsl:character-map name="raquo.ent">

         <xsl:output-character character="'" string="&amp;apos;"/>
         <xsl:output-character character="&#39;" string="&amp;apos;"/>
      < /xsl:character-map>

< xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" use-character-maps="raquo.ent"/>
```

Can anyone help? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please show the XSLT which process that text. You can use `<xsl:value-of select="..." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>` to prevent escaping.

Comment: @khachik, in fact it is in the <xsl:apply-templates select="."/> which process the text, i don't know how to use the character-map for it.

Comment: you can use `disable-output-escaping="yes"` as in the comment above.

Comment: @khachik, I tried, it doesn't work....I wrote as <xsl:apply-templates select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"
    use-character-maps="raquo.ent"/>

    <xsl:character-map name="raquo.ent">
     <xsl:output-character character="&#34;" string='&amp;#34;'/>
     <xsl:output-character character="&#39;" string='&amp;#39;'/>
    </xsl:character-map>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<cell i='0' j='0' vi='0' parity='Odd' subType='-1'>&#34;String&#39;</cell>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<cell i="0" j="0" vi="0" parity="Odd" subType="-1">&#34;String&#39;</cell>
```

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev thank  you, but how do you test it? It still doesn't work here:(

Comment: @Jamie: I always test my solutions -- this one was run with Saxon 9.1.07 and XQSharp. If you're running Altova, file a bug to them.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev It seems that the character-map doesn't work in XSLT 1.0.It's not valid for the pages. What can I do?

Comment: @Jamie: Yo need to install and use an XSLT 2.0 processor. `<xsl:character-map>` is an XSLT2.0 - only feature.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: As this is from a project of our company, I don't know whether it will support XSLT 2.0. Do you know any other method other than the character-map?

Comment: @Jamie: I asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985615/preserving-entity-references-when-transforming-xml-with-xslt I ended up not using XSLT for this particular task, but as a really ugly work-around you could try pre-processing your instance and replacing every `&` with `&amp;` so your entities look like `&amp;#34;`. You would then need to post process your instance after your XSLT transform and replace all `&amp;` with `&`.